# addView時にドラッグしたViewがリセットされてしまう

Tags: android, android-layout

動的に追加したviewをドラッグ出来るようにしているのですが、
View.layoutで設定した座標が、layoutにaddViewした時点でリセットされてしまいます。
コレを回避する方法は無いでしょうか？

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public Activity mActivity;
    public RelativeLayout layout;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {}

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        ImageView dragView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        DragViewListener listener = new DragViewListener(dragView);
        dragView.setOnTouchListener(listener); 

        return rootView;
    }


    public void addImageView(){
        ImageView v = new ImageView(mActivity);
        //v.setL
        layout.addView(v, new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        v.setImageDrawable( mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ueki));
        DragViewListener listener = new DragViewListener(v);
        v.setOnTouchListener(listener);

    }


    //ドラッグイベント処理
    public class DragViewListener implements OnTouchListener {
        // ドラッグ対象のView
        private ImageView dragView;
        // ドラッグ中に移動量を取得するための変数
        private int oldx;
        private int oldy;

        public DragViewListener(ImageView dragView) {
            this.dragView = dragView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getRawX();
            int y = (int) event.getRawY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int left = dragView.getLeft() + (x - oldx);
                int top = dragView.getTop() + (y - oldy);
                dragView.layout(left, top, left + dragView.getWidth(), top
                        + dragView.getHeight());
                break;
            }
            oldx = x;
            oldy = y;
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        mActivity = activity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View#layout()`は`View`の表示位置を変更しますが、これは本来親の`ViewGroup`が各々の子の`View`のレイアウトパラメータから位置を計算してから呼び出すものです。レイアウトパラメータそのものを変えるものではありません。

動的に`View`を追加した場合、親の`ViewGroup`はオリジナルのレイアウトパラメータから再度位置を計算しようとします。そのため、元の位置に戻ります。

例えば以下のようなコードを追加して、`ACTION_UP`のタイミングでレイアウトパラメータを更新する処理を入れてみてはどうでしょうか？

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     lp.setMargins(dragView.getLeft(), dragView.getTop(), 0, 0);
     dragView.setLayoutParams(lp);
     break;
```